# What is the default Enum value size in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm having the error *data truncated for column 'manager' at row 1* when inserting a new value for a Enum type field in a MySQL table.

I do not want to modify the enum values size because it would require modifications on a production-ready system. However I can not find what is the default size for values in a Enum.
( I already checked this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html)

Extra info:
My Enum definition
ENUM('client','taquatoa','api-client')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens not only when size of the inserting value is higher than the specification (for any other value type) but also when inserting a value that does not correspond with the enum specification.

My error was that I didn't notice that the api-client value was not updated for that file. So MySQL throws this error when the value is not part of the enum. Pretty simple.

Also for answering the question, I've found that the default Enum value size is determined by the value of bigger size in the enum declaration, so its modified when altering the table and adding a new enum.

Notice, this error could also happen if using Hibernate, JPA or another ORM and defining an specific length for a field.